# How can I find scholarly articles that are not written in English?

Tags: reference-request

I usually need to find some articles in other languages (French and German, etc). I googled the reference provided on the book but I seldom found what I need. For example, how can I find this article
[image]

What website should I use? I tried to use my university's library but I couldn't find any such articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aid of Google ("elem math") to find the journal and then [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org) to get the right page number, I found it here:

https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=edm-001:1965:20#142

It's [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org) (which gives limited but useful access to everybody) and [AMS Math Reviews](http://www.ams.org/mr-database) (if you are a member or have access via your institution) that are the real stars here: people that I talk to who work in Computer Science and many other disciplines are amazed to learn that mathematics has these wonderful resources that collate so much of the literature.

Comment: Thank you for the websites and helping me to find this article.

Comment: I went to this website https://zbmath.org/citationmatching/ and found an article that is different from yours. How can I find the one you provided?

Comment: I just did a Zentralblatt search for "Flor" as author, "Ungleichung" in the title and year 1965. I have never used the citation matching link.

Comment: Hmm.. I used the way you suggested but I got the same result https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0145.05102.

Comment: That gives you the review, from which you can see that the page number in your original citation is wrong. If you use the right page number ....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the article, see if your university has access to the journal in which the article is published. If you can login to the journal's website using your university credentials then they should have a database of all publications and you can find it there by tracking the year/volume number.

Comment: I searched for Wagner, Elem. Math., but nothing related to a journal showed up.

Comment: Elem. Math. is the abbreviation for the journal name (it is in italics), Wagner is part of the title. Googling 'Elem. Math. journal' should give what you're after.